# Error location always from root of site?

Tags: spring, servlets, web.xml

I have this XML in my `web.xml` file:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/html/404</location>
</error-page>
```

If I go to a page like `/indexer` (which doesn't exist), then I get redirected properly to the URL `/error/html/404`. If I go to a page like `/index/nope` (which also doesn't exist), then I a blank page and the URL reads `/index/error/html/404`. What can I put in the `location` tag to always get the correct URL, regardless of where I started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not normal behaviour. It should definitely be relative to the context root. I cite from page 154 of the [Servlet 3.0 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html):

> The subelement `location` element contains the location of the resource in the web
>   application relative to the root of the web application. The value of the location
>   must have a leading `‘/’`.

Your problem is caused by a bug in the servletcontainer used. Report it and/or upgrade to latest version. Or, perhaps you've a bad `Filter` intercepting on `ERROR` dispatcher for an URL pattern of `/*` which is using the `RequestDispatcher#forward()` wrongly.

---

**Update** as per the comments, you're using Tomcat 7.0.16, which is a Servlet 3.0 compatible container. Although your `web.xml` is declared conform Servlet 2.5 instead of 3.0, I can't reproduce your problem with both `web.xml` versions on my local Tomcat 7.0.11, 7.0.19 nor 7.0.22. Also, the URL does not change here in browser address bar (and is not supposed to change). Just the original (wrong) URL remains in browser address bar. This makes me think that this is more likely caused by a bad filter or possibly a front controller servlet which is mapped on a too generic URL pattern of `/*` and is sending a redirect to the wrong URL. Check for such a filter or servlet in your webapp, debug and fix it accordingly.

Comment: If I understand what you are saying correctly: My XML is OK, the problem is the Spring servlet container?

Comment: Spring is (among others) a DI framework, not a servletcontainer. The servletcontainer is where you deploy the webapp to. E.g. Tomcat 7.0.22, Glassfish 3.1.1, JBoss AS 6.0.0, etc. Knowing the exact make/version of the servletcontainer would be helpful in order to naildown the problem more and/or attempt to reproduce it and/or to report it appropriately. Telling what Servlet API version your `web.xml` is declared to would also be helpful.

Comment: I am using Apache Tomcat 7.0.16 and my `web.xml` starts with `<web-app version="2.5" ...>`. The `xsi:schemaLocation` indicates 2.5 as well.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have 7.0.16 at my hands, but I can't reproduce your problem on 7.0.22 nor 7.0.11 which I have here (also not on 7.0.19). See answer update.